# System Crash 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, steam

I use a sony-vaio(VPCEH15EN) laptop with 8GB(2x4) ugraded memory. **The system has crashed on several occasions.**

1. opening games on steam
2. upgrading os from 20.04 to 20.10
3. typing specific commands on the terminal(such as lshw)**

The screen freezes for a while neither the mouse nor the keyboard work and shut downs itself or I have to manually press the power button.

**Along with the system crash issue sometimes after installing the updates the software updater asks for restart of the system. When I click on restart the system just shut downs. It doesn't even restart I have to press the power button to start it again.**

I tried looking for solutions and could not find any proper one. Need help regarding the issues mentioned in bold.

```
ls -al /var/crash
    total 80
    drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie  4096 Nov 29 15:56 .
    drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root      4096 Jul 20  2016 ..
    -rw-r-----  1 aditya   whoopsie 66514 Nov 28 19:40 _usr_bin_blueman-tray.1000.crash
    -rw-r--r--  1 aditya   whoopsie     0 Nov 23 11:33 _usr_bin_blueman-tray.1000.upload
    -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie    37 Nov 23 11:33 _usr_bin_blueman-tray.1000.uploaded


free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.0Gi       5.3Gi       183Mi       1.4Gi       6.3Gi
Swap:         1.0Gi          0B       1.0Gi

   
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 10


sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
R0180Z9
```

[Memtest86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCKKJ.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema I cannot show you the output of `sudo lshw -C memory` as the system crashed will executing the command. All the other command outputs are displayed above.

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema, sorry for the delay. I have tested my memory and I have passed 3 tests. Attached screenshot above.Memtest86

Comment: @heynnema the solution helped me in a partial manner. The problems are still there, neither I can upgrade to 20.10(as it gets stuck in the process and crashes) nor can I reboot(while I click on reboot it shutdowns and I have to boot by pressing the power button). Could please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Did you do ALL the portions in my answer? Did you research any BIOS updates further? You **may** need to go back to 18.04 to get a reliably working system on your older VAIO. Create a Ubuntu Live 18.04 USB flash, boot it, and see if you can do the lshw command without crashing. Do the same test with a 20.04 and 20.10 flash key. Report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Sony VAIO VPCEH15EN

You have BIOS R0180Z9 from 04/28/2011.

I couldn't find a newer BIOS for you, as your computer is very old, but you might look [here](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/downloads/results?query=VPCEH15EN+bios).

**memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**vm.swappiness**

vm.swappiness=10 is totally inappropriate for your configuration.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 8G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

**swap**

Your /swapfile is way too small at 1G. Let's increase it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```